# Compare Groups User is in in Active Directory to permissions a group has on a server in C#

Tags: c#, permissions, active-directory, ldap

I figured out how to get all the groups a user is in within Active Directory, but now what I need to do is compare these groups to local machine groups and view the permissions.

Is there a way to do this in C#? I know you can't do it directly using Active Directory API but maybe there's some way of combining the AD API with something else?

Comment: What permissions are you trying to view? You can use the [LSA] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721849(v=vs.85).aspx) to get local security information.

Comment: I did a pretty bad job of describing what I want.  

Basically: I start with a user's groups in AD  

Now I want to compare those groups to a local machines groups, and see what groups match within each local machine group.

For example: I have a user who is in the group Developers within Active Directory.  

I now want to find what machine groups have Developers as a part of it.